# PL/SQL UTL_HTTP send multiple raws

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I'm trying to send with webservice POST method a dozens of records to other side but problem is that other side get only one raw of data.
I put cursor and in begin section open cursor and make loop.
I think the problem is somewhere in part UTL_HTTP.read_raw. I have to add something additional or modify function.
Where is the catch, where I'm wrong?

create or replace FUNCTION "TST" return clob is

```
l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
l_buffer_size    NUMBER(10) := 20000;
l_line_size      NUMBER(10) := 50;
l_lines_count    NUMBER(10) := 20;
l_string_request VARCHAR2(32767);
l_line           VARCHAR2(128);
l_substring_msg  VARCHAR2(20000);
l_raw_data       RAW(20000);
l_clob_response  CLOB ;
v_clob clob;
url varchar2(200) := 'http://tst';

cursor c_get_prihod is 
select     IDORIG   ,    IDSUSTAVA  ,    DATUM  ,    SIFAGENCIJE    ,    SIFDRZAVE  ,
SIFOSUSL    ,    IZNOSNETO  ,    IZNOSBRUTO ,    IZNOSPOREZA    ,    SIFHOTELA
from HRS_LASERLINE_PRIHOD
where datum = pms_p.business_date
and sifhotela = pms_p.resort
;

begin

for a in c_get_prihod loop

l_string_request:= 
'{
IdOrig:"'||a.IDORIG||'",
IdSustava:"'||a.IDSUSTAVA||'",
Datum:"'||a.DATUM||'",
SifAgencije:"'||a.SIFAGENCIJE||'",
SifDrzave:"'||a.SIFDRZAVE||'",
SifOsUsl:"'||a.SIFOSUSL||'",
IznosNeto:"'||a.IZNOSNETO||'",
IznosBruto:"'||a.IZNOSBRUTO||'",
IznosPoreza:"'||a.IZNOSPOREZA||'",
SifHotela:"'||a.SIFHOTELA||'",
}}'
;

end loop;

l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request(url , method => 'POST', http_version => 'HTTP/1.1');
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', length(l_string_request));

BEGIN

<<request_loop>>

FOR i IN 0..CEIL(LENGTH(l_string_request) / l_buffer_size) - 1 LOOP
    l_substring_msg := SUBSTR(l_string_request, i * l_buffer_size + 1, l_buffer_size);

BEGIN
    l_raw_data := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_substring_msg);
    UTL_HTTP.write_raw(r => l_http_request, data => l_raw_data);

EXCEPTION

WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
EXIT request_loop;

END;
END LOOP request_loop;

l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

BEGIN

LOOP
    UTL_HTTP.read_raw(l_http_response, l_raw_data, l_buffer_size);
    l_clob_response := l_clob_response || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(l_raw_data);
END LOOP response_loop; 

EXCEPTION

WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
    UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
END; 

<<print_response>>

FOR i IN 0..CEIL(LENGTH(l_clob_response) / l_line_size) - 1 
LOOP
    l_line := SUBSTR(l_clob_response, i * l_line_size + 1, l_line_size);
EXIT WHEN i > l_lines_count - 1;
END LOOP print_response;

v_clob:= l_clob_response;        

return v_clob ;

exception
  when utl_http.end_of_body then
  utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
end;
end TST;
```

Comment: Are you expecting `c_get_prihod ` to return dozens of rows? And what debugging have you done to check what is being produced, sent and received? Also - which version of Oracle are you using - built-in JSON functionality was added from 12cR1; pretty basic initially but has been expanding since.

Comment: Yes c_get_prihod returns dozens of raws which should be transfer via webservice. They recieved only one record. Oracle version is 11.2.0.4.20

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor query might find dozens of rows, but you're doing this:

```
for a in c_get_prihod loop

l_string_request:= ... ;

end loop;
```

Each time around that loop you're *replacing* the entire contents of `l_string_request`, so however many rows you get and how many times you go around the loop, you'll always end up with that containing *only* the last row returned by that query. So you only send that single, final, record to the web service.

Assuming the receiving service is expecting an array of records, you might want something like:

```
begin

  l_string_request := '[ ';

  for a in c_get_prihod loop
    if a.FLAG > 1 then
      l_string_request := l_string_request || ', ';
    end if;
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '{ ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"IdOrig": "' || a.IDORIG || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"IdSustava": "' || a.IDSUSTAVA ||' ", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"Datum": "' || a.DATUM || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"SifAgencije": "' || a.SIFAGENCIJE || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"SifDrzave": "' || a.SIFDRZAVE || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"SifOsUsl": "' || a.SIFOSUSL || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"IznosNeto": "' || a.IZNOSNETO || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"IznosBruto": "' || a.IZNOSBRUTO || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"IznosPoreza": "' || a.IZNOSPOREZA || '", ';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || '"SifHotela": "' || a.SIFHOTELA || '"';
    l_string_request := l_string_request || ' }';
  end loop;
  
  l_string_request := l_string_request || ' ]';

  dbms_output.put_line(l_string_request);

  ...
```

where `flag` is an extra column added to the cursor result as e.g. `, ROWNUM AS FLAG` - just as a mechanism to know if you are on the first row or a subsequent row (and so need as comma between array elements).

The `dbms_output` lets you see the entire generated value, which you can manually inspect and/or pass through a JSON validator to check it is what you (and more importantly the receiving service) expect to see. You can still add newlines during the JSON construction for readability, though the service won't care about those.

Depending on how many rows you could have you might need `l_string_request` to be a CLOB instead of a `varchar2`. I'd also suggest you explicitly format date/timestamp values, and handle numbers properly if you have any of those.

---

> After modification according to your advice I'm getting this error:
>
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error ORA-06512: at "OPERA_MARRIOTT.HRS_LASERLINE_BI_PRIHOD", line 87

You would get this if `l_clob_response` is empty, so perhaps your read loop isn't getting what you expect now. (Which may well be because the request is now invalid JSON, or doesn't match what the service expects). After the `UTL_HTTP.get_response()` call, see what `l_http_response.status_code` and `l_http_response.reason_phrase` show. The status codes [are in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_http.htm#BABJHJJA).